# Removing the "commerce" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

A "commerce" tag was created a few days ago and all questions asked have been related to Craft Commerce.

Can somebody delete the "commerce" tag so users are more inclined to use the "plugin-craftcommerce" tag?

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce

Comment: Good thinking, @luke!

Comment: @MattStein Maybe provide an answer (i.e. Done!), so Luke can mark this as the answered?

Comment: Good catch, @DouglasMcDonald, thank you!

Comment: I've noticed a similar situation with the tags `entries` and `entry` with the plural form having the most questions and an extensive tag wiki. Could this also be resolved? @DouglasMcDonald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! (Thanks for the nudge to answer, Douglas.)